# Problem with with the sum of a divergent sequence $\rightarrow +\infty$ and a lower bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Im trying to prove that if $a_n\rightarrow+\infty$ and $b_n$ is lower bounded only, then $a_n + b_n\rightarrow+\infty.$ I have to use the definition of a divergent sequence but I'm stuck. $\forall M > 0,\ \exists ν\in N : an > M\forall n > ν.$ That is the definition that I'm using. I know that I have to use the fact that $b_n$ is a lower bounded sequence so $∃A<b_n.$ Can some help?

Comment: $a_n+b_n >M$ if $b_n >b$ and $a_n >M-b$.

Comment: But how do I know that a_n+b_n>M ∀M > 0?

Comment: You *don't*. But you *do* know that $a_n>M-b$ and $b_n>b$ implies that $a_n+b_n>M$.

Comment: I still dont get how a_n+b_n>M implies that my sequence is divergent. Doesn't that only say that my sequence is greater than a certain M? But for divergence it has to be greater than all M? Sorry if the question seems stupid but I'm really troubling to understand it.

Comment: Can your question be clearer? Indeed $a_n+b_n$ tends to infinity not only if $b_n$ is lower bounded

Comment: @X0-user-0X I didn't say that it only diverges when $$b_n$$ is lower bounded. I just want to understand why it diverges in that specific case.

Comment: If $b$ is the lower bound , then $a_n+b_n\ge a_n+b$ for every $n$. Now just show that $a_n+b$ tends to $\infty$ , and you are done.

Comment: Thats actually a great idea. Thank you.

Comment: @Randomdude Ok i ve written a full anwser hope i ve understood you well and that it will help you.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my answer if i have well undestood your question. But take into account that i am just a student.

First let recall that by definition: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n= \infty$ means that: $\forall M \in \mathbb{R} , \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \; s.t. \; \forall n > N \Rightarrow a_n> M$ (i)
On the other hand it is given that $b_n$ is lower bounded. That means $\exists A \in \mathbb{R} \; s.t. \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow b_n > A.$ (ii)

Now if we writte $c_n = a_n + b_n$ it cames that for all $M' \in \mathbb{R} $ we can define $M'-A$ for which (according to (i) ) , it exists at least one $N' \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $a_n > M' - A$.
So we have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}> N' \Rightarrow c_n=a_n+b_n>M'-A + b_n$.
But by (ii) we know too that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow b_n>A$, hence if it is true $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is in particular true $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}> N'$.
To conclude we have $\forall M' \in \mathbb{R} , \exists N'$,as define from $a_n$ just above, s.t. $\forall n > N' \Rightarrow c_n > M'$.
And this is the definition of: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }c_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n + b_n = \infty$

Q.E.D.